# Enable Disable Gradle Offline Mode In Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated my Android Studio recently to 3.6.1
But I am unable to find the option to toggle the Gradle Offline mode. Any help would be appreciated. I need help urgently. Please help.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have found solutions watch this video https://youtu.be/lbCM8N8ItRI

Comment: Thanks for this question, this is what I was looking for. The first asked question wasn't accurate enough to find.

Comment: This question is better asked than the one marked as duplicate. That question does not even mention android studio 3.6 in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answers.

Comment: If the icon is unchecked means gradle is online?