# Android Studio 3.6.3 enable/disable offline work?

Tags: android, android-studio, offline, android-studio-3.6

I cannot find the Gradle **Offline** Build Option in **Android Studio 3.6.3**.
It used to be in Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle and there was the offline work option.

So, how do I make offline work changes now?

Comment: I found the answer from the StackOverflow suggestion though, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481987/no-cached-version-gradle-plugin-available-for-offline-mode.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from the StackOverflow suggestion though, at

[No Cached Version Gradle Plugin Available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481987/no-cached-version-gradle-plugin-available-for-offline-mode)

and this

[Enable Disable Gradle Offline Mode In Android Studio 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495080/enable-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio-3-6-1)